# Expo Swift Pods Statis Libraries Issue

Tags: ios, firebase, static, expo

I was building expo app for IOS and I was getting that error because I had used firebase in my project.

ERROR:
[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Install pods build phase for more information.

I tried many answers from internet but all these were related to react native and pod files etc